# Flutter: How to get this type of TimerWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement this type of timer widget in flutter

Widget I am looking for
[image]

Is there any prebuilt widget in the flutter library or any packages that anyone can suggest.

Comment: maybe https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_time_picker_spinner/). Read more about this package on the official documentation.
check out this demo
[image]